# How to add total for calculated (using expression)column in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Column expression:

```
IIf(Left(Fields!EmployeeNo.Value,1)<>"2",Count(Fields!EmployeeNo.Value),"")
```

TOtal expression is:

```
Sum(IIf(Left(Fields!EmployeeNo.Value,1)<>"2",Count(Fields!EmployeeNo.Value),""))
```

if use this expression for total getting message as `"#Error"` in report preview.

Please tell me how to get this done.

Comment: Hi, why you use Left? this EmployeeNo.Value have any letter? if this column have a letter you can't use sum. Try this =Sum(IIf(Left(Fields!EmployeeNo.Value,1) <> "2", 1 , 0))

Answer (score 0):

Your column expression doesn't need a `Count` - that is for aggregation across multiple rows. Your total expression also can't have a `Sum` and a `Count`.

Try this for your column expression:

```
=IIF(Left(Fields!EmployeeNo.Value, 1) <> "2", 1 , 0)
```

and sum that for your total expression:

```
=Sum(IIF(Left(Fields!EmployeeNo.Value, 1) <> "2", 1 , 0))
```